# Maximum callstack size Vite / Page keeps reloading

Tags: docker, vue.js, vite

I'm using vite with rails and loading my custom-component like this:

main.js

```
import { defineCustomElement } from 'vue';
import Panel from '~/components/panel_custom/Panel.ce.vue';


const CustomElement = defineCustomElement(Panel);
window.customElements.define('panel-custom', CustomElement);
```

erb file

```
<panel-custom data="<%= props %>"></panel-custom>

<%= vite_javascript_tag 'note_panel' %>
```

When now opening the page it keeps reloading permanently. When commenting the import of my component the continuous reload stops. I thought it mioght be a problem in the component itself, but commenting all javascript didn't fix the problem. And even using an empty component didn't fix it. Is there a problem in including the custom-component?

EDIT:

The problem might be the HMR of vite. Setting:

```
server: {
    hmr: false
  },
```

in vite.config.js at least solved the problem in one component. But also disabled the hmr...

Comment: Have you enabled `disable cache` in your browsers devtools?

Comment: @tauzN Nope, it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the `vite.json` when using Docker. The host configuration was missing:

```
  "development": {
    "autoBuild": true,
    "publicOutputDir": "vite-dev",
    "port": 3036,
    "host": "0.0.0.0"
  },
```